# Attacking with a blade in main hand while holding a bow in off-hand in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

This seems like such a silly question to ask, but it's something that occurred to me when making my character build.  The character I'm making is a human ranger|cleric hybrid multiclassing into avenger (for roleplay reasons).  I'm also using a Hybrid Talent feat to get Prime Shot, so that with the multiclass feat means I can't take Quick Draw (though that's one I plan on getting later).

I know that sheathing and drawing a weapon take a minor action each without Quick Draw, which is why I'm trying to find ways to go from melee to ranged attacking or vice-versa without having to drop a weapon.  So, would it be possible to hold the bow in the off-hand while attacking with a one-handed melee weapon such as a longsword in the main hand?

Comment: As a helpful tip, hybrid... plus MC tends to be abysmal. As part of [Dragon #394](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/394/394_ReflavoringPower.pdf) it has guidelines on reflavouring your powers such that you can accomodate your desired narrative without... well... situations described above.

Comment: The bigger problem here is if you try to do ranged _and_ melee attacks equally well, you will end up sucking at them both. Always specialize!

Answer (score 2):

You are *allowed* to *hold* a two handed bow in a single hand and attack with the weapon in your other hand.

However, the action economy of this will *eventually* require dropping the sword.

Basically, you can always take your hand off the bow for free, draw the sword as a minor, attack with the sword as a standard, and then stow the sword as a minor and be holding just the bow, and not have any actions left.

However, if you want to switch between melee and ranged regularly, the hand crossbow is the best option. This may be the kind of thing you take through L1 and switch to a bow at L2 when you can take Quick Draw.

So yes this works, it's just super action intensive, and may not be worth doing. I'd recommend trying on the Hand Crossbow for size instead.